# Android Board Game: Many views or one big view?

Tags: android, 2d, 2d-games

I'm trying to make a 2D turn based android game that features a grid like board. I have thought up of two different methods of rendering the board:

1. One big custom `View` that calculates everything and renders all the tiles. Any animation on any one tile will require the whole view to be re-drawn; so this view will be re-drawing itself all the time.
2. A big custom `ViewGroup` with many smaller custom `View`s, each `View` representing a single tile. Only tiles that animate need to be redrawn. The `ViewGroup` is responsible for making sure each `View` is in the correct location on the screen.

What might be the less resource intensive method? Or is there perhaps an even better method I haven't thought of?

Other factors that may need to be taken into account:

- Aside from the grid tiles there will be sprites that animate and also move between tiles. The tiles themselves do not translate.
- The number of tiles on the board is different from game to game but the board is always rectangular.
- The board is often so big that a typical screen will not fit all the tiles; so the user should be able to pan and zoom on the board.

Comment: It really depends on the game you plan on making. Creating a lot of separate views sounds like it could get messy if you are doing a good bit of updating. What happens if something is between views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for a big custom `View`.

If all you are worring about is being less efficient in the drawing process, then you can use `invalidate(Rect)` et simila to invalidate just some small dirty region. This will redraw only a small region of the `View`. A big custom `View` will also simplify animations and other drawing that cross tiles borders.

For implementing pinch-zoom functionalities, take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale.html#scale)

Why not a game engine such as [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/blog/)?

Comment: Bear also in mind that from API 14+, hardware acceleration is enabled by default. Basically you get the OpenGL speed for free still using the Canvas API

Comment: Using an android engine definitely is a good alternative to writing it from scratch.